# Is array of characters another way of representing String constant in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
char a[ ]= "HELLO";
```

Can we say that the HELLO above is a string constant.I have a doubt in this, because we can change the string elements like `a[0]='A'`. So, can we still claim `"HELLO"` here as a string constant just because it contains a `NULL` at the end?

Comment: "HELLO" is a string constant. `a` is an array of `char`s that's initialized from a string constant. The End.

Comment: C or C++?  In C++ `"text"` is called a string literal

Comment: @NathanOliver: C99 §6.4.5 calls them string literals too.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Cool.  Thanks.  Wasn't sure if C called them the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `"HELLO"` is still a string constant (more particularly, it is a string *literal*).

However, the array `a`, whose contents were initialised to be a copy of that constant, is not.

Answer (score 2):

`"HELLO"` is a string literal - it is stored as an array of `char` in such a way that it is available over the lifetime of the program.  It *may* be stored in a read-only memory segment, depending on the implementation (on my system, it is).  Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal leads to undefined behavior.

`a` is not a string literal - it's an array of `char` that's *initialized* with the contents of the string literal `"HELLO"`.  You can change the contents of `a` as you wish (although you can't store a string longer than 5 characters to it).

Here's a short program to show the relationship between the string literal `"HELLO"` and the array `a` (along with a pointer thrown in for good measure):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dumper.h"

int main( void )
{
  char a[] = "HELLO";
  char *p = "HELLO";

  char *names[] = { "\"HELLO\"", "a", "p" };
  void *addrs[] = { "HELLO", a, &p };
  size_t sizes[] = { sizeof "HELLO", sizeof a, sizeof p };

  dumper( names, addrs, sizes, 3, stdout );

  return 0;
}
```

`dumper` is a utility I wrote that displays the memory map for each object.  When compiled and run, we get the following output:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
    "HELLO"        0x400b30   48   45   4c   4c    HELL
                   0x400b34   4f   00   22   48    O."H

          a  0x7fff89062330   48   45   4c   4c    HELL
             0x7fff89062334   4f   00   00   00    O...

          p  0x7fff89062328   30   0b   40   00    0.@.
             0x7fff8906232c   00   00   00   00    ....
```

The string literal `"HELLO"` is stored as a sequence of ASCII (or UTF8) characters starting at address `0x400b30`.

The array `a` is stored starting at address `0x7fff89062330` - as you can see, it contains a *copy* of the string `"HELLO"`.

The pointer `p` is stored starting at address `0x7fff89062328` - it stores the *address* of the string literal `"HELLO"` (x86 is little-endian, so multi-byte values are stored starting with the least-significant byte - you'll need to read from right-to-left, bottom-to-top).

One thing you notice is the difference in addresses between `"HELLO"` and the variables `a` and `p`. On my system, `"HELLO"` is stored in the `.rodata` memory segment:

```
$ objdump -j .rodata -d strings2

strings2:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000400b2c :
  400b2c:       01 00 02 00 48 45 4c 4c 4f 00 22 48 45 4c 4c 4f     ....HELLO."HELLO
  400b3c:       22 00 61 00 70 00 41 64 64 72 65 73 73 00 49 74     ".
  ...
```

`a` and `p` are allocated from the runtime stack, which starts at a high address and grows "downwards" towards lower addresses.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A constant is a variable that doesn't change (or should not change) through the execution of a program. As long as you can do `a[1] = 'd'` it's not a constant.

To define a constant string in c, you could do it three ways:

```
#define WHATEVER = "HELLO";
const char WHATEVER[] = "HELLO";
static const char WHATEVER[] = "HELLO";
```

Other definitions won't create a constant string, but a mutable char array, which is a different thing.

Comment: `const char* WHATEVER = "HELLO";` is the simplest, safest and fastest (on balance).

Comment: @BoundaryImposition still, making it `static` limits the scope to the file, so there are occasions where it is safer than a plain `const` variable. And when it comes to macros, yes, it's safer to declare a `const` value than a macro since they are handled at preprocessor and are not type-safe.

Comment: The main difference I wanted to point out was `*` vs `[]`, as yours produces an unneeded copy.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition my bad, didn't see the `*`

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a string, but not a string constant. A string is a null-terminated array of characters. A string constant would have to be immutable. When a string appears in code as defined with double quotes (eg. `"hello"`), it's considered a string literal. The actual character array in the memory would be a string.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not a string constant in C. By the way, any string in C language has to terminate with '\0', example:

```
// '\0' explicitly included as the last element
char str[] = "HELLO";  

// '\0' has to be the last element in this case
char str2[] = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', '\0'};
```

If you want to add a string constant in your C code, here is an example:

```
const const_str[] = "HELLO";
```

Another example of constant string:

```
#define CONST_STR "HELLO"
```

Comment: or `const char* str = "test";`. Bringing macros into this just confuses the issue.